# Firefox is getting crashed when trying to launch Firefox using appium code in emulator

Tags: testing, firefox, mobile, appium, appium-android

We are trying to launch Firefox browser in emualtor using the below mentioned capabilities to execute Responsive web application test cases. But the Firefox is getting crashed.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();         
JSONObject firefoxoptions=new JSONObject();
firefoxoptions.put("androidDeviceSerial","emulator-5554"); 
firefoxoptions.put("androidPackage","org.mozilla.firefox");
capabilities.setCapability("androidStorage", "internal");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName","windows");
capabilities.setCapability("browserName","firefox");
capabilities.setCapability("automationName","Gecko");
capabilities.setCapability("moz:firefoxOptions",firefoxoptions);

WebDriver driver= new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Tried with different Geckodriver and Firefox versions, but still firefox is getting crashed.

Facing the same issue in real device as well.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try passing moz:firefoxOptions as a Map instead of a JSONObject:

```java
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("androidDeviceSerial","emulator-5554"); 
map.put("androidPackage","org.mozilla.firefox");
capabilities.setCapability("moz:firefoxOptions", map);
```